# fail2ban failregex apparently not banning

Tags: fail2ban

After noticing repeated attempts to access supposed webadmin resources on my server in blocks by the same ips (i.e. repeated attempts from each ip in a long list of 'common' server webadmin resources, e.g. /phpmyadmin, /mysql, etc.), I've set up a custom fail2ban filter (and jail) which tested successfully in fail2ban-regex against my apache2/access.log, showing 55 'hits' (seems about right without checking):

`[INCLUDES]
before = apache-common.conf
[Definition]
failregex = '^<HOST> - - .*"GET \/phpmyadmin|"GET \/phpMyAdmin|"GET \/pma\/|"GET \/myadmin|"GET \/admin|"GET \/mysql.*$'
ignoreregex = ''`

The fail2ban.log shows the new jail loaded. However, none of several offending ips in the current apache2/access.log is listed in the fail2ban.log after restart.

My understanding of f2b is that it bans against current logs without waiting for new log entries.

Does this indicate the new filter and jail aren't working as intended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, `fail2ban` ignores any log entries which are older than `findtime` setting for a jail (default is 600 seconds).

Comment: Yeah, the new filter/jail appears to be working (banning) now, but throwing "No 'host' found" errors in the fail2ban.log. I removed the single quotes around my regex but this didn't help.

Comment: Fixed the error by throwing parentheses around the boolean-delimited string. Seems to be all good now.